# Laravel - Relationship With Resources and whenLoaded Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-relations, laravel-resource

So I am trying to control output utilizing resources as I was told it's the best way to model the data for api output.

Customer Model

```
 public function invoices () {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Invoice');
    }
```

Invoice Model:

```
public function customer() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Customer');
    }
```

Customer Resource:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'invoices' => InvoiceResource::collection('invoices')
        ];
    }
```

Invoice Resource:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $customer = $this->whenLoaded('customer');
    return [
      'id' => $this->id,
      'customer' => CustomerResource::collection($this->whenLoaded($customer)),
    ];
}
```

Customer Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $customers = Customer::with(['invoices']);
        return CustomerResource::collection($customers->paginate(50))->response();
    }
```

But when I go to the API EndPoint

```
Error
Call to a member function first() on string

Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection::collectResource
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/CollectsResources.php:30
```

Error Starts in Stack from:
`return CustomerResource::collection($customers->paginate(50))->response();`

Answer (score 1):

Each Invoice has only one Customer, right? so:

```
'customer' => new CustomerResource($this->whenLoaded('customer')),
```

Also what is `$` sign before `customer`??

Answer (score -1):

I had two issues
1st issue
Invoice Resource:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $customer = $this->whenLoaded('customer');
    return [
      'id' => $this->id,
      'customer' => CustomerResource::collection($this->whenLoaded($customer)),
    ];
}
```

needed to be

```
{
    $customer = $this->whenLoaded('customer');
    return [
      'id' => $this->id,
      'customer' => CustomerResource::collection($this->whenLoaded($customer)),
    ];
}
```

Second Customer Rsource:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'invoices' => InvoiceResource::collection('invoices')
        ];
    }
```

needed to be

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'invoices' => InvoiceResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('invoices'))
        ];
    }
```